# Order list by queryset count in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

Sorry this is basic, but I'm new to Python and Django.

I have a list of users who have performed an action that is being saved in a separate table. I want to show a list of these users, sorted by how many times they've taken the other action.

I understand how to get the counts:

```
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    print user.action_set.count()
```

And I understand how to show the counts in my template:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.action_set.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I'm not sure how to have it sort the users by the count of the action set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotate / Aggregation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

```
from django.db.models import Count
users = User.objects.annotate(action_count=Count('action')).order_by('action_count')
# note that this also saves your extra query PER user object.

{% for user in users %}
   {{ user.action_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

For future reference, **if you couldn't sort by the DB**, you can python sort any list...

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.method())
```

Very useful.